# How do I make a timeout command in discord python?

Tags: python, discord.py

so this might sound like I am a noob, but I have been trying for a while now and I cant make it work so I hope you can help me.
I want to make a timeout command so I can just type ".mute [user] [time in either days (with d after the amount of days) or hours (with h after the amount of hours)] [reason]". So for example if I want to mute Alex for 7 days, I have to type `.mute @Alex#0001 7d Reason`. Now I've tried to check if it's a "h" or "d" at the end (for hours and days) which works, but if I then try to remove the letter from the string it doesnt work. (and the other code doesnt work either for some reason) Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, reason):
    if ctx.author.id == member.id: 
        await ctx.channel.send(":x: You can't ban yourself!")
        return
    if "h" in time:
        time.replace("h","")
        print(time)
        await member.timeout(until=datetime.timedelta(hours=time), reason=reason)
    if "d" in time:
        time.replace("d","")
        print(time)
        await member.timeout(until=datetime.timedelta(days=time), reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f":white_check_mark: {member.name} has been successfully muted.")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: `time` is still a string after the `replace()` call, while `timedelta()` wants numbers as I see. Try `hours=int(time)` and `days=int(time)` respectively.

Comment: @tevemadar hey, so I've added a `print(time)` between the replace and the timeout and it seems like the h or d didnt even get removed. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Haha, yes. Strings are immutable in many high-level languages, including Python. So you get back a new one, the line should be `time=time.replace("h","")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually solved it myself... it could've been multiple problems but what got it to work in the end is that I used `member.timeout_for` instead of `member.timeout`. (I also had to do some other things, but they don't really matter here.)

Answer (score 0):

For other people seeing this question, here i put in some code to timeout a user for a specific time

Note: made it within a cog and with slash commands

```
@app_commands.command(name='timeout', description='timeouts a user for a specific time')
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
async def timeout(self, interaction: Interaction, member: Member, seconds: int = 0, minutes: int = 0, hours: int = 0, days: int = 0, reason: str = None):
    duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, minutes=minutes, hours= hours, days=days)
    await member.timeout(duration, reason=reason)

    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{member.mention} was timeouted until for {duration}', ephemeral=True)
```